# Transparent image curved outline (not rectangle border)

Tags: css

I want to create a border animation on hover on a transparent image like so.

[image]

Can this be done with css?

(Of course without creating two images - one without the border and one with the border - and changing the image on hover)

I am open to using a small js library if there is, but not jQuery.

Comment: You say "without creating two images", but since the graphic in your post is one image, why not take it and use it for sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Outline With Apparent Distance

To mimic what you show in the image, you can do this...

[image]

```css
.laptop {
  margin:50px;
  background:url(https://i.imgur.com/PQcP7AC.png) no-repeat;
  width:400px;
  height:220px;
  transition:0.2s all;
 
}
.laptop:hover{
  filter: drop-shadow(4px 0 0 white) drop-shadow(0 4px 0 white) drop-shadow(-4px 0 0 white) drop-shadow(0 -4px 0 white) drop-shadow(6px 0 0 orange) drop-shadow(0 6px 0 orange) drop-shadow(-6px 0 0 orange) drop-shadow(0 -6px 0 orange);
}
```

```html
<div class="laptop">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a `drop-shadow` css property (as shown in other answers) to mimic the offset requires creating a bigger drop shadow with the desired color, and then covering it up with a narrower shadow with the background color. If we want to have a universal solution that would work for any image placed on any background, we would need to leverage svg filters (for reference see [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Applying_SVG_effects_to_HTML_content)), since css does not yet give us such capabilities. It has a very good [browser coverage](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-filters) (basically IE10+). I have created such filter in the snippet below.

The `<filter>` node embedded into the example was created with [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) using the filter creation tool, then extracted from the saved .svg file. The comments inside the `<filter>` node indicate which parameters need to be changed to tweak the final result sizing and colors. I have also added a slight background color to show, that the effect is independent of the background and creates the outline ignoring a slight drop shadow present on the source image (right below the laptop).

In case you need more information on how the effect is composed, let me know in the comments.

```css
img:hover{
  filter:url(#outline);
}
html {
  background-color: rgb(255, 244, 216);
}
```

```html
<svg height="0">
    <filter
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
       id="outline">
      <feComponentTransfer
         result="result10">
        <feFuncR
           type="identity" />
        <feFuncG
           type="identity" />
        <feFuncB
           type="identity" />
        <feFuncA
           type="gamma"
           tableValues=""
           intercept="10"
           amplitude="10"
           exponent="7"
           offset="0" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <!-- change the stdDeviation here for the outer diameter -->
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="7"
         in="result10" />
      <feColorMatrix
         values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 500 0 "
         result="result2" />
         <!-- change the stdDeviation here for the inner diameter -->
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="4"
         in="result10"
         result="result5" />
      <feColorMatrix
         values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 500 0 "
         result="result4" />
         <!-- change the flood-color here the outline color -->
      <feFlood
         result="result1"
         flood-color="rgb(255,165,0)" />
      <feComposite
         in="result2"
         in2="result4"
         operator="out"
         result="result3" />
      <feComposite
         in2="result3"
         operator="in"
         in="result1"
         result="result8" />
         <!-- change the stdDeviation here to smooth out the final outline -->
      <feGaussianBlur
         stdDeviation="0.3"
         result="result6" />
      <feBlend
         mode="overlay"
         in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
</svg>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyyKx.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the `drop-shadow` filter to have a similar effect:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyyKx.png) left/200% 100% no-repeat;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.box:hover {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 10px red);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

For this particular image and as suggested by @Mr Lister you can do this:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyyKx.png) left/200% 100% no-repeat;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.box:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 0 0px #fff) 
  drop-shadow(0 5px 0 #fff) 
  drop-shadow(-5px 0 0px #fff) 
  drop-shadow(0 -5px 0 #fff) 
  drop-shadow(4px 0 0px #fa2) 
  drop-shadow(0 4px 0 #fa2) 
  drop-shadow(-4px 0 0px #fa2) 
  drop-shadow(0 -4px 0 #fa2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Yes. Or, to make it look more like the OP's original, `.box:hover{
      filter: drop-shadow(5px 0 0px #fff) drop-shadow(0 5px 0 #fff) drop-shadow(-5px 0 0px #fff) drop-shadow(0 -5px 0 #fff) drop-shadow(4px 0 0px #fa2) drop-shadow(0 4px 0 #fa2) drop-shadow(-4px 0 0px #fa2) drop-shadow(0 -4px 0 #fa2);`

Comment: @MrLister Yes I avoided this because I thought it can be any kind of image and this combination of drop-shadow won't be good in all the cases. Let's say, that for each image we need to tweak it.

Answer (score 1):

The `drop-shadow()` CSS function applies a drop shadow effect to the input image.
Read more about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) Web Docs.

```css
img{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  transition:0.2s all;
}
img:hover{
  filter:drop-shadow(4px 0 0px red) drop-shadow(0 4px 0 red) drop-shadow(-4px 0 0px red) drop-shadow(0 -4px 0 red);
}
```

```html
<img src = "https://i.imgur.com/2oyDKF3.png">
```

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a single property to do what you want directly on the image. You could do this with a SVG path (border) placed on the image and show/hide it on hover with opacity, with svg you save surely something in performances, alas there is no more other safe ways to do this.